# CouchDB SSL CRT to PEM files

Tags: powershell, ssl, https, openssl, couchdb

I have tried several ways to get some PEM files to be used by CouchDB. I have generated a cert with powershell, exported it with key to a pfx and then used openssl to convert to 2 pem files and installed them in Couch. With this approach it seems to work in IE11, but it doesn't work with firefox or other browsers. Firefox produces this error:

> The key does not support the requested operation. (Error code:
>   sec_error_invalid_key)

I've also gotten a free ssl cert from ssl.com, (they gave me three CRT files) and tried converting it using openssl, but to no avail.

I've also followed the instructions on the page from CouchDB to generate a self signed cert specifically for this purpose, but it will not load the page. (http://docs.couchdb.com/en/latest/config/http.html#config-ssl about half way down)

Has anybody had success with this? How do I get my certs into a format that will play nice with Couch and will all browsers?

UPDATE:
Now I'm getting this error

> A PKCS #11 module returned CKR_DEVICE_ERROR, indicating that a problem has occurred with the token or slot.

Not sure if this is a step forward or backwards...

Comment: Is putting a reverse proxy in front of CouchDB an option? It could then handle HTTPS and you don't have to deal with it in CouchDB: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy

Comment: I may end up coding a nodejs middleware, but it would be nice if this would work. As couch states on their page about it, it's supposed to be *easy*. :-/

Comment: I have the same problem. Using CouchDB 1.4 on Ubuntu 13.10. Curl works fine though with the unsecured flag (-k).

Answer (score 0):

It [seems](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-2028) like CouchDB versions predating 1.7 or 1.6 are not able to have intermediate certificates specified for certificate verification. Since you are writing about having received three .crt files, (s)ome of those might be required as intermediate certificate(s). CouchDB not knowing about them can be the cause of your problem.

Apparently, one way to work around this is to concatenate your certificate file along with the intermediate certificate file(s). Simply `cat` them together like

```
$ cat yours.crt theirs.crt > couchdb.crt
```

...and use CouchDB's `certfile` configuration option to point to `couchdb.crt`'s location.
If you prefer to convert .crt to .pem first, use sth like

```
$ openssl openssl x509 -in yours.crt -inform der -outform pem -out yours.pem
```

In a new enough version, you can probably use an intermediate certificate by setting CouchDB's `cacertfile` option. Have a look at [this](http://terinstock.com/blog/2014/07/02/tls-with-erlang.html) for further information.